# Accepting arguments by argparse

Tags: python, argparse

What is the Difference between `nargs='*'` and `nargs='+'`?

As they both accept one or more arguments.

```
parser.add_argument('nums',narg='*')
```

And

```
parser.add_argument('nums',narg='+')
```

Comment: From [python docs for argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs): `'+'. Just like '*', all command-line args present are gathered into a list. Additionally, an error message will be generated if there wasn’t at least one command-line argument present.` Take note of the last sentence - that is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` is following the common usage in `re` syntax. quoting from https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

> *
>   Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.
>
> +
>   Causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE. ab+ will match ‘a’ followed by any non-zero number of ‘b’s; it will not match just ‘a’.
>
> ?
>   Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

You can also use `argparse` constants, which have the same string values

```
argparse.ONE_OR_MORE
argparse.ZERO_OR_MORE
argparse.OPTIONAL
```